# iterate over list of friends on facebook in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

How can I iterate over the IDs of the list of friends of a user of facebook with id say 123 in PHP?

Comment: You better start with FB API basics: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: The [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is used to find connections between things on Facebook. You should start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the api, somthing like:

```
 $result = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/friends?fields=name,gender',array('access_token' => $access_token));
```

to get an array of friends.

Now in order to go over them you need to access the friend data in each item, like this:

```
foreach($result['data'] as $key => $friend){
             //access any data item you want, such as ['id']...  

            }
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: For friend ID 123, just replace $uid :)